# Why `clojure.set/union` function accept other type of data as input?

Tags: clojure, union

I'm learning Clojure and I found something surprised me, as mentioned in title. As [doc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.set/union) said, the `clojure.set/union` function

> Return a set that is the union of the input sets

However I tried to input other type sequences and it gives me some result instead of telling me the input type is wrong. For example

```
user=> (clojure.set/union '(1 2 3) '(2 3 4))
(4 3 2 1 2 3)
```

Here I expected Clojure to warn me my inputs are not sets, but it returns another list with duplicate inside, which is also opposite to what is stated in document("Return a set").

I'm wondering why this function is designed like this and what benefits it provides than giving a type error. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I would prefer to see more type checking, Clojure often adopts a "garbage in, garbage out" type of philosophy.  In this example, it extends to ***assuming*** that you provide 2 sets to the `union` function.

Looking [at the source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/set.clj#L20):

```
(defn union
  "Return a set that is the union of the input sets"
  [s1 s2]
     (if (< (count s1) (count s2))
       (reduce conj s2 s1)
       (reduce conj s1 s2)))
```

you can see it simply appends the shorter input onto the longer input using `conj`.  For a sequential list or vector, this adds the 2nd list of items (one at a time) to the front of the 1st list, which your example shows.

Comment: Thanks @Alan ! The source code explains everything on its behavior. Though I think a more reasonable return on list input should be an exception.

Comment: Yes, me too. Or, at least, coerce into a set first.